# How do I count primitive operations in this algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

**Firstly:** What is the *T(n)*, and thus *O(n)* of the following Pseudo-Code?
How can I go through and count operations for code like this when the inner for-loop has a variable limit?

**Secondly:** What are the primitive operations to look for as I am struggling to count them exactly.

I understand it isn't necessary to count the exact number of primitive operations (for *O(n)*) but knowing how to do so that would make me more comfortable calculating the 'big picture'.

```
Input: X, a 1-D numerical array of size n
1) Let A = an empty 1-D numerical array of size n ~T1 = 1 or n  
2) For i = 0 to n-1                               ~T2 = n (multiplies T3 to T8)                     
3)    Let s = X[0]                                ~T3 = 1                     
4)    For j = 1 to i                              ~T4 = ? multiplies T5                     
5)       Let s = s + X[j]                         ~T5 = 2 reads and 1 set? Or 1 operation if using +=?                     
6)    End For                                     ~T6 = 0                   
7)   Let A[i] = s /(i+1)                          ~T7 = 1 set and 1 or 2 reads                     
8) End For                                        ~T8 = 0  
Output: An n-element array A of numbers such that A[i]
        is the average of elements X[0],X[1], … ,X[i]
```

Any materials/resources/Qs that sharpen primitive operation counting (with answers) are greatly appreciated.

Comment: I understand that this particular algorithm is inefficient as I have calculated it's subjective runtime against another more efficient algorithm.

Comment: This is not java, and you are just stating a textbook question without evidence of having worked on it. Also, this is pure theory: while instruction-counting is good when learning about complexity, it has little to do with real-world performance on a given machine. You may want to post this question on cstheory.stackexchange.com

Comment: What you might consider to be a primitive operation is subjective in this situation (even more so than if it was written in Java)

Comment: I was testing the algorithms in Java hence my mistake... tag removed.

Comment: You might consider each line to be a primitive operation for a hypothetical machine. That way you could count the number of lines executed. Line 2 for example, might be considered 1 + n operations or up to 1 + 8 * n operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it seems the easiest way to break this problem down is by working out the total for each line immediately, rather than multiplying afterwards. The clarifications are:

- T<sub>1</sub> Setting an array of any size is `1` operation
- T<sub>2</sub> The setting of a For loop is the range of i: `n`
- T<sub>3</sub> 1 read plus 1 set times n, `2n`
- T<sub>4</sub> Using the logic of the first for loop on the secondary one and counting towards a small n instead of trying to multiply immediately, we see we'd have 0 (discounted because `for j=1 to 0` makes no sense) + 1+2+...+(n-1). Now we use the famous Sum formula S<sub>x</sub>=x(x+1)/2 except here we're using n-1 so S<sub>n-1</sub> = (n-1)(n-1+1)/2 = **(n<sup>2</sup> - n)/2**
- T<sub>5</sub> is read+read+add+set, 4 operations, times it's immediate `for` loop giving **2(n<sup>2</sup>-n)**
- T<sub>6</sub> is 0 as it's just marking the end of the `for` loop
- T<sub>7</sub> can be guessed (not certain) as going left to right: set+read+divide+read+add, 5 operations, times the outside `for` loop's size which means **5n**
- T<sub>8</sub> see T<sub>6</sub>

THUS adding T<sub>n</sub> for 1 to n gives us the unattractive:

T(n) = 1 + 5.5n + 2.5n<sup>2</sup>

O(n<sup>2</sup>)

TL;DR: work out each line individually, use sum of first n natural numbers formula, use small n if too difficult to do in abstract.

**Initially this confused me as I was working with non-integer coefficients for T(n), but the result is always an Integer :)**

Answer (score 0):

I would count separately the reads/writes to an array, the arithmetic operations and the number of for loop iterations.

In the inner loop (4-6), `i` reads, `i` +, `i` for.

Then in the outer loop (2-8), `n` reads, `n` inner loops (`i=0 to n-1`), `n` +, `n` /, `n` writes, `n` for.

In total, `(n+1)n/2` reads, `n` writes, `(n+1)n/2` +, `n` /, `(n+1)n/2` for.

I am counting these separately because their execution time can be highly architecture dependent and also data-type dependent. Other operations, such as moves of local data (held in register) are somehow absorbed in the former.

Clearly, for large `n` (say `>25`) the reads, accumulations and loops dominate. For very large `n`, due to cache effects, you can expect the reads alone to dominate.