# Add increment to count primitive operations

Tags: c++, bubble-sort, primitive

I am trying to count the primitive operations in this bubble sort algorithm. I know that this is in O(n). I need to add counters to count the primitive operations. However, i am confused as to where i should place the counters, especially in the for loop. This is the code in c++. Thanks

```
void bubbleSort(int arr[], int n)  
{  
    int i, j;
    bool swapped; 
    int comparisons=0;  
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)  {
     swapped = false;
    // Last i elements are already in place  
    for (j = 0; j < n-i-1; j++)
    {
        comparisons++;
        if (arr[j] > arr[j+1])  
            {
                int temp = arr[j];
                arr[j]=arr[j+1];
                arr[j+1]=temp;
                swapped = true; 
            }  
    }
    if (swapped == false) 
        break;  
    }
    cout << "Number of comparisons = " << comparisons << endl;
}
```

Comment: This is not O(n).

Comment: Bubble sort has both worst case and average complexity of O(n^2), not O(n).  In any event, the problem of counting "primitive operations" depends on which operations you want to count.     It's non-trivial, since a loop construct introduces several operations on each iteration, and something like `arr[j] = arr[j+1]` involves multiple operations (eg.  evaluating `j`, adding `1` to it, adding `j` and `j+1` to `arr` to obtain pointers,  dereferencing those pointers, accessing `arr[j+1]`, copying its value to `arr[j]`).   That's why people don't tend to resort to counting operations in code

Comment: i'm sorry but why this is not o(n). I thought bubble sort best case is o(n)?

Comment: @Sarawat - Yes, the best case complexity of bubble-sort is O(n) - but that only occurs in the particular case where the array is already completely sorted. Unless you expect your data to be sorted most of the time (i.e. rarely needing to be sorted), then worst case and average complexity are more important - and for bubble sort they are both O(n^2)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I count primitive operations in this algorithm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42751706/how-do-i-count-primitive-operations-in-this-algorithm)